# Deny Error SQL 1142

Tags: mysql, select, sql-grant

I have installed 4 phpbb3 forums ru in my server in same SQL database but in separate databases inside.
And i want share phpbb_Users table!
I follow the steps dcz wrote in: http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=562513&start=45#p6498115, 
but after put $table_shared in config.php and constants.php, this error is show:

General Error - SQL ERROR [ mysqli ]

```
SELECT command denied to user 'sql1234_user'@'localhost' for table 'phpbb_config' [1142]
An sql error occurred while fetching this page. Please contact an administrator if this problem persists.
```

Allready try to GRANT user but show same error, user acess deny to GRANT.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and found this through a Google search, thought I would post my solution in case someone came across this.

My error was the exact same. The problem was my `JOIN` syntax, here is what I had:

```
"SELECT * FROM aircraft_sched INNER JOIN aircraft_sched.Sched_Day1 ON aircraft_sched_options.SchedOpt_ID"
```

Here is what it should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM aircraft_sched INNER JOIN aircraft_sched_options ON aircraft_sched.Sched_Day1 = aircraft_sched_options.SchedOpt_ID"
```

I had typed it before thinking, just a dumb error on my part. Hopefully this helps someone.